# How can I reliably show a native google map on Trigger?

Tags: google-maps, trigger.io

How can I reliably show native google maps in Trigger?

*Here's the background:*

I'm showing Google Maps on Trigger.io using backbone, copying the format on the Trigger blog here: http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/05/15/how-to-build-a-location-based-hybrid-mobile-app-with-reverse-geocoding/

Now, on my friend's phone, these maps show up as native maps. On my phone, the maps show up as javascript embedded maps (they have pinch-to-zoom, and are noticeably slower).

Both phones are running Android, though his is running v4, and mine is 2.3.x.

What am I missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using Trigger.io with Google Maps, you are not using 'native maps' at all so I'm not sure exactly what you mean here. If your phone is at the older Android version then I would expect it to be a lot slower.

Maybe you could provide screenshots to demonstrate the differences you're seeing other than performance?